# Prevent SML type from becoming eqtype without hiding constructors

Tags: sml

In `datatype` declarations, Standard ML will produce an equality type if all of the type arguments to all of the variants are themselves `eqtype`s.

I've seen comments in a few places lamenting the inability of users to provide their own definition of equality and construct their own eqtypes and unexpected consequences of the SML rules (e.g. bare `ref`s and `array`s are eqtypes, but `datatype Foo = Foo of (real ref)` is not an eqtype).

Source: http://mlton.org/PolymorphicEquality

> one might expect to be able to compare two values of type real t, because pointer comparison on a ref cell would suffice. Unfortunately, the type system can only express that a user-defined datatype admits equality or not.

I'm wondering whether it is possible to *block* eqtyping. Say, for instance, I am implementing a set as a binary tree (with an unnecessary variant) and I want to pledge away the ability to structurally compare sets with each other.

```
datatype 'a set = EmptySet | SetLeaf of 'a | SetNode of 'a * 'a set * 'a set;
```

Say I don't want people to be able to distinguish `SetLeaf(5)` and `SetNode(5, EmptySet, EmptySet)` with `=` since it's an abstraction-breaking operation.

I tried a simple example with `datatype on = On | Off` just to see if I could demote the type to a non-eqtype using signatures.

```
(* attempt to hide the "eq"-ness of eqtype *)
signature S = sig
  type on
  val foo : on
end

(* opaque transcription to kill eqtypeness *)
structure X :> S = struct
  datatype on = On | Off
  let foo = On
end
```

It seems that transparent ascription fails to prevent `X.on` from becoming an eqtype, but opaque ascription does prevent it. However, these solutions are not ideal because they introduce a new module and hide the data constructors. Is there a way to prevent a custom type or type constructor from becoming an `eqtype` or admitting equality without hiding its data constructors or introducing new modules?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer is no. When a type's definition is visible, it's eq-ness is whatever the definition implies. The only way to prevent it being eq then is to tweak the definition such that it isn't, for example, by adding a dummy constructor with a `real` parameter.

Btw, small correction: your type `foo` should be an equality type. If your SML implementation disagrees then it has a bug. A different case is `real bar` when `datatype 'a bar = Bar of 'a ref` (which is what the MLton manual discusses). The reason that the first one works but the second doesn't is that `ref` is magic in SML: it has a form of polymorphic eq-ness that user types cannot have.

Comment: R.e. the `bar` case, my mistake. SML/NJ rejects the `datatype 'a bar` case you describe, but in the `datatype foo = Foo of (real ref)` case I had in the question initially it just emits a nasty warning about calling `polyEqual`.